# Get localstorage value without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am changing language based on the options in dropdown menu i used localstorage to change the language but i have to refresh the page to get the value updated in localstorage is there is any way to get the value in local storage  without refreshing the page in reactjs i am using react intl for language change option

```
changeLanguage = (language) => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("siteLanguage", language);
    this.setState({})
    window.location.reload(1);
}
readTextFile(`/app/localization/localization.en.json`, 
(localizationContent) => {
        let localization = JSON.parse(localizationContent);
        this.props.setLocalizationMessages(localization.messages, 'en');
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem("siteLanguage") == "th") {
        readTextFile(`/app/localization/localization.th.json`, 
(localizationContent) => {
            let localization = JSON.parse(localizationContent);
            this.props.setLocalizationMessages(localization.messages, 
'th');
        });
    }
```

Comment: I doubt you are seeing the issue you describe. The localStorage is set immediately without updating but your code to change the language is not executing until you reload and read the value you just set - perhaps just remove the first `}` ?

Comment: @mplungjan i have to refresh the page to get the updated value in reactjs

Comment: Put readTextFile inside your changeLanguage. Remove the reload part.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what if readTextFile code is another component

Comment: I would have expected something like this: `changeLanguage = (language) => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("siteLanguage", language);
  readTextFile(\`/app/localization/localization.${language}.json\`,
    (localizationContent) => {
      let localization = JSON.parse(localizationContent);
      this.props.setLocalizationMessages(localization.messages, language);
    });
}`

Comment: Why do u even need to use the localStorage?  I guess you are using it because you want the site language to stay the same even on refresh. To do that you can use redux persist. That will save your state even on refresh.